# jQuery mobile list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am giving my users the option to use ckEditor to build content for their mobile sites.
When adding a ordered or unordered list, if the link is the hole content of the list like:

```
<li><a href="http://somepage.com">Some Link</a>
```

The everything works fine.
But if the user adds something like

```
<li>This is <a href="http://acura.html">the link</a> to some site</li>
```

Then the list is displayed wrong.
The css puts the link in a weird position - with all the elements and tags that jquery mobile adds and its default css.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in your question the second example is invalid html, it closes the anchor tag twice and doesn'[t close the LI.

```
<li>This is <a href="acura.html">the link</a> to some site</a>
```

should be

```
<li>This is <a href="acura.html">the link</a> to some site</li>
```

Not sure if this solves your issue, but just something i noticed.

Comment: Thanks for that - I fixed the error on my question. But that was not the cause of the problem - just a typo when posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you include `<A>` tags within listviews, jQM makes some assumptions about what you are trying to do and 'enhances' the link in a particular way.  I think an easy way to override this and get an inline link is to surround the link in a `<span>`:

```
<li>This is <span><a href="#">the link</a></span> to some site</li>
```